# what is the differnece between resourceLangId and editorLangId in vs code extension development?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am developing and extension which requirements is that it should work only with css files ( .css, .scss and .less ) file

I have key binding added in **package.json** for execution of command but problem is that now it is available for any file, so to make this condition, searching the document and found this [when clause context](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts). and added in **package.json**

#### package.json

```json
keybindings": [
      {
        "command": "css-color-collector.collect",
        "key": "ctrl+f7",
        "mac": "cmd+f7",
        "when": "(editorTextFocus && editorLangId == css) || (editorTextFocus && editorLangId == scss)"
      }
    ],
"languages": [
      {
        "id": "css",
        "extensions": [
          ".css", ".scss", ".less"
        ],
        "aliases": [
          "css",
          "sass",
          "scss",
          "less",
          "CSS",
          "SCSS"
        ],
        "mimetypes": [
          "text/css"
        ]
      }
    ],

    "menus": {
      "commandPalette": [
        {
          "command": "css-color-collector.collect",
          "when": "editorLangId == css || editorLangId == scss ||  editorLangId == less"
        }
      ]
    }
```

but extension still activate for other than css file?

further I see there is an option under [resoure contexts](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-contexts)

**resourceLangId** ?

so my question is what is the significant difference between **resourceLangId** and **editorLangId** and which one we have to use?

addition query

- Is there is any shorter way to add all condition in *when* clause

currently writing

```js
(editorTextFocus && editorLangId == css) || (editorTextFocus && editorLangId == scss)
```

but

```js
editorTextFocus && (editorLangId == css) || editorLangId == scss)
```

doesn't seem to work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use case there is no real difference between `resourceLangId` and `editorLangId`.  They both will have the active text editor's language ID.  `resourceLangId` can additionally be used to indicate what resource, like a file or folder has been right-clicked on in the Explorer - the `editorLangId` will not give you that value.

So `resourceLangId` can be used in a context menu when clause when you want to know which file/folder was right-clicked on and whether to show a command in the resulting context menu.

You should continue to use `editorLangId` since you have no use of the extra functionality of `resourceLangId`.

---

This is the shortest when clause I could think of that works for what you want to do - the right side is a regular expression.

```
"when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId =~ /^(css|scss|less)$/i"
```

This also works:

```
"when": "editorTextFocus && (editorLangId == css || editorLangId == scss || editorLangId = less)"
```