# Why does my context menu item in the VS Code explorer tree only show up after the file is opened?

Tags: vscode-extensions

In my extension, I've added a new context menu item for C/C++ files to the Explorer pane, using a section like this in package.json

```
      "explorer/context": [
        {
          "command": "myExtension.myCommand",
          "when": "resourceLangId == cpp || resourceLangId == c",
          "group": "2_workspace"
        },
```

However myCommand only shows up after a file open action.  For example, if I open a folder containing: foo.java and foo.cpp, the menu is not shown until I open either of the files,
and it's displayed properly when all editors are closed after this first open action.

Also, it doesn't seem to matter if the extension is activated or not, the behavior is the same.

**Update** I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75847245/what-is-the-differnece-between-resourcelangid-and-editorlangid-in-vs-code-extens)  that seems to indicate that resourceLangId should be available for items in the tree while editorLangId indicates the language of the active editor

Comment: I can't reproduce this using your `when` clauses. I do not have to actually open any `cpp/`c` file to get the command to show in the context menu of such a file in the Explorer.  Is it possible to link to a repository so I can look at it?

Comment: Sure, here you go:  [repo](https://github.com/vectorgrp/vector-vscode-vcast)

Answer (score 0):

The menu item only appears after your extension was loaded. You can define different events when that has to happen. You have not posted your entire package.json but I assume your [activation event](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events) is set to `onLanguage`, which triggers activation when the first file for that language is opened. Use the wildcard event (`*`) if you really need that menu item to be available all the time.

As per your comment, you are using a file based activation for your extension. In this case no resource language ID is available, since you haven't opened any resource yet. You could use a different `when` clause, but then the item would be available in context you probabyl don't want it to be. It makes perfect sense that an item, which is supposed to exist only for editors with a specific language ID, only show when such an editor is opened.

Comment: This is not the case, the menu item appears before the activation is triggered.  (A break point on the activation handler is not hit)    Automatic activation is triggered by the existence of a file:  `"activationEvents": [
    "workspaceContains:**/UNITDATA.VCD"
  ],`